# Prevent empty array records from being submitted in to MYSQL database using php

Tags: php, mysql

I want to prevent the empty records in an array from being submitted to  the MYSQL database:

HTML part:

```
<input type="text" name="m_name[]" value="name"/>
<input type="text" name="m_lastname[]" value="lastname"/>
<input type="text" name="m_name[]" value="second_name"/>
<input type="text" name="m_lastname[]" value="second_lastname"/>
<input type="text" name="m_name[]" value=""/>
<input type="text" name="m_lastname[]" value=""/>
```

and this is the PHP and MySQL part:

```
if(!empty($_POST['m_name'])) $m_name = array_map('mysql_real_escape_string', $_POST['m_name']);
if(!empty($_POST['m_lastname'])) $m_lastname = array_map('mysql_real_escape_string', $_POST['m_lastname']);

for($l=0; $l < count($m_name); $l++){
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO `group_members` SET
            `m_name` ='".$m_name[$l]."', 
            `m_lastname` ='".$m_lastname[$l]."'"
    );
}
```

The problem is that all the 6 inputs, whether those which does not include any values are being submitted to the database. What am I doing wrong?!

Comment: `count($m_name)` gets size of text or..?

Comment: gets the number of strings in array

Comment: Whats problem, you are not checking other 6

Comment: Empty members of the array will not just disappear, you need to check if `$m_name[$l] and $m_lastname[$l]` contains any actual data before issueing the update

Comment: Why you can't add before `mysql_query("INSERT ...` condition `if (!empty($m_name[$l]) and !empty($m_lastname[$l]))` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since nobody answered the question, I finally got how to do it and I will share it because somebody will encounter my problem and get in this question by chance:

Simply use `array_filter()`, which conveniently handles all this for you:

```
$m_name = array_filter(array_map('mysql_real_escape_string', $_POST['m_name']));
$m_lastname = array_filter(array_map('mysql_real_escape_string', $_POST['m_lastname']));
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that the problem is that in case that the `$m_name` is not empty but `$m_lastname` is empty then the for loop will be executed and the field `m_lastname` from table`group_members` will be empty after insertion.